# Clear floats after every second div

Tags: html, css

I have following HTML markup. There are two .item divs in a row, each of them having a different height.

Is it possible to clear the floats after every second div without changing the markup? Every second div has the class .last-item.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item last-item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item last-item"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrap{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.item{
    width: 50%;
    background: yellow;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/R7VHX/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
.item:nth-child(2n+1) { clear: both; }
```

This is equivalent to:

```
.item:nth-child(odd) { clear: both; }
```

which clears *after* every second item (in other words, every third).

More info at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`nth-child(odd)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector :

```
.item:nth-child(odd){
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: It should be .item:nth-child(odd)